# Links to Workspaces and Builder missing in Digital Experiences - All Sites section in Production

Tags: community, experience-cloud, experience-builder-page

In Production, I'm a System Administrator. Yet I can't seem to get the links to Workspaces and Builder to show up in the Digital Experiences > Sites section (See screenshot of what it should look like; screenshot taken from my dev org). Is this a limitation of Production orgs? Meaning I have to make changes in Dev/Test and push to Production via changeset?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It was a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your profile has to be a Member of the community: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387677&type=1

> If your profile is not selected in the site's Administration Members
> Setup as outlined in Add Members to Your Experience Cloud Site
> documentation, no action (Manage or Workspaces and Builder) will be
> available upon viewing the site via Setup, enter All in the Quick Find
> box, click on All Sites